# Class not registered 0x80040154

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, exception, networking

I get a "Class not registered 0x80040154" error when i run my application. My environment setup is windows 2008 using visual studio 2005. I just migrated from windows xp, where the application used to work with no error. Thanks!

Comment: We aren't prophets, show some code.

Comment: @Griwes when i call CoCreateInstance the program HRESULT fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dll or exe that provides the interface defined by the CLSID that you are passing to CoCreateInstance either does not exist on your new PC or if it does exist it has not been registered.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to register, or "install" a COM server that your application uses.